# how to use function from another class in flight php

Tags: php, constructor

I am new in flight php.
I need some help, I create two classes client.class.php and deliveryServiceConnector.class.php and i have index.php. I want to use function from deliveryServiceConnector.class.php in client.class.php so I write this code:

```
    public function __construct() {
    $this->connector = new deliveryServiceConnector(DOLIBARR_API_KEY,DOLIBARR_ROOT_URL,NuLL, $this->nodeName);
    $connector->testDisplayDev();

}
```

I got this error:

> Undefined variable: connector (8)
> Any idea how can i fix my error, Thanks

Comment: you may need to declare connector inside your class, can you please share the whole class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the same thing for the `deliveryServiceConnector`. In the first line, inside the function, you use `$this->connector`, but in the second line you use `$connector`. Therefore it is undefined. Try to use the same thing twice. Either:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->connector = new deliveryServiceConnector(DOLIBARR_API_KEY,DOLIBARR_ROOT_URL,NuLL, $this->nodeName);
    $this->connector->testDisplayDev();

}
```

or

```
public function __construct() {
    $connector = new deliveryServiceConnector(DOLIBARR_API_KEY,DOLIBARR_ROOT_URL,NuLL, $this->nodeName);
    $connector->testDisplayDev();

}
```